# Uncaught (in promise): Error Cannot instantiate object new is missing

Tags: sapui5

I have a controller:

Menu.Controller.js:

```
sap.ui.define([
       "sapit/ext/utils/BaseController",
       "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
       "sap/ui/model/Sorter",
       "sap/ui/model/Filter",
       "sapit/nova/model/constants",
       "sapit/ nova /model/formatter",
       "sapit/ nova /util/Helper",
       "sapit/ nova /util/Validator",
       "sapit/ nova /util/ItemService"
     ], function(BaseController, JSONModel, Sorter, Filter, constants, formatter, Helper, Validator, ItemService) {
       "use strict";

       return BaseController.extend("sapit.nova.controller.Menu", {

             formatter: formatter,
             helper: new Helper(),
             itemService: new ItemService(),


             onInit: function() {
               this.fragmentProcess = sap.ui.xmlfragment("sapit.nova.view.fragment.Process", this);
               // attach events
               this.getRouter().attachRouteMatched(jQuery.proxy(this.onRouteMatched, this));
             },
             onRouteMatched: function(oEvent) {
                 var oPage = this.byId("menuProcessor");
                 var sRouteName = oEvent.getParameter("name");

                 if (sRouteName === "Menu") {
                   // show fragment
                   this.helper.clearFragment(oPage);
                   this.helper.showFragment(oPage, this.fragmentProcess);
                 }
```

I have the corresponding xml view as Menu.view.xml:

```
mvc:View controllerName="sapit.nova.controller.Menu" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
    <Page id="menuProcessor" title="{i18n>menuPageTitle}" showNavButton="false">

    </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

My router config is:

```
"routes": [{
    "pattern": "/admin",
    "name": "Main",
    "target": ["menu"]
  },

  "targets": {
    "menu": {
      "viewName": "Menu",
      "viewLevel": 1,
      "controlAggregation": "masterPages"
    }
```

The problem is when I run this application control is going to onInit () of the menu.controller but it's not going to onRouteMatched although it's getting the instance of router attached to this view.

Every time i run this application i am getting an Error after entering the onInit() and rest of code doesn't work and view doesn't come up.

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot instantiate object: "new" is missing!
    at constructor (sap-ui-core.js:640)
    at constructor (sap-ui-core.js:1601)
    at constructor (sap-ui-core.js:1571)
    at f (sap-ui-core.js:638)
    at f (sap-ui-core.js:284)
    at p (sap-ui-core.js:285)
    at _ (sap-ui-core.js:286)
    at Object.properties (sap-ui-core.js:286)
    at l (sap-ui-core.js:298)
    at B.getText (sap-ui-core.js:296)
```

Can you please suggest me in this regard.

Thanks !!

Comment: Voting to close since the relevant code is missing to reproduce the issue. And the author has abandoned this question.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the spaces from sap.ui.define this might be a problem when loading Helper, Validator and ItemService

```
sap.ui.define([
        "sapit/ext/utils/BaseController",
        "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel",
        "sap/ui/model/Sorter",
        "sap/ui/model/Filter",
        "sapit/nova/model/constants",
        "sapit/ nova /model/formatter",
        "sapit/ nova /util/Helper",
        "sapit/ nova /util/Validator",
        "sapit/ nova /util/ItemService"
    ],
```

Answer (score -1):

You did not instantiate your fragment.

Try this :

```
this.fragmentProcess = new sap.ui.xmlfragment("sapit.nova.view.fragment.Process", this);
```

Comment: `sap.ui.xmlfragment` is a factory function and therefore doesn't need the `new` keyword.